# 2 dim list implementing a chessboard

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
1. EMPTY = "-"
2. ROOK = "ROOK"
3. board = []
4. for i in range (8):
5.    for j in range (8):
6.        board[i][j] = EMPTY

7. board[0][0] = ROOK
8. board[0][7] = ROOK
9. board[7][0] = ROOK
10.board[7][7] = ROOK

11. print(board)
```

The above code throws an error in line #6, while line #7 to #10 works fine.
The error is: `IndexError: list index out of range`.
Why am I getting this error, while a similar format (line #7 to #10) is working fine?

I just started with Python, and I am finding it difficult to reason things out.

Comment: Line 7 onwards is not executed... You know an exception stops the program, right?

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 2):

`board` is a 1 dimensional empty list, you can't index it using `board[i][j]` but you **can** append new items to it. Try this:

```
...
for i in range (8):
   board.append([])
   for j in range (8):
       board[i].append(EMPTY)
...
```

This should print (formatted for clarity):

```
[
 ['ROOK', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'ROOK'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['ROOK', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'ROOK']
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the list before you can index it. I recommend a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
board = [[EMPTY for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]
```

I'm using `_` as a dummy variable, since its value doesn't actually matter.

Comment: or `[EMPTY] * 8` for the inner one, given that `EMPTY` refers to an immutable object